# Получение родительского объекта из дочернего

Tags: java, android, классы, объекты

Существует примерно такой код:

```
Class  parent {

          public child c=new child();

           public void load(){


          .....К этому методу надо добраться 
            из дочернего объекта, 
            созданного из дочернего класса child...

                             }

      class child {

        public void save(){


     ...вот отсюда надо получить
       доступ к объекту(или его методу load()),
       созданному из parent класса:
     то есть Big.load();
   ....

                         }
               }

}

parent Big= new parent();
```

Как такую задачу решить и возможно ли?

Answer (score 1):

Это делается через CallBack.
Начнем с дочернего класса ChildClass. В нем ты объявляешь интерфейс

```
interface SomeListener {
     void load()
}
```

Создаешь переменную этого интерфейса

```
SomeListener listener;
```

и собственно сам метод определение слушателя

```
public void setListener(SomeListener listener){
this.listener = listener;
}
```

Теперь базовый класс и в нем реализуешь метод load

```
Class BaseClass implements ChildClass.SomeListener{
 public void load(){
      // код
 }
}
```

Теперь в первом классе при вызове

```
listener.load()
```

будет вызывать класс из верхнего класса

Comment: Добавлю что из внутреннего класса свободный доступ в родительскому классу. Вчера вопрос был не отформатирован и я не заметил это

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тупо передал в конструктор `child` класса ссылку на объект `parent`.

В конструкторе `child` записал бы эту переменную в приват и в методе `save` дернул метод `load` у сохраненной переменной `parent`.

Возможно, для `java` это работать не будет.